# How to display a number of type Float64 upto one decimal place only

Tags: c, numbers, decimal, printf

I have a variable , Float64 min;
I want to display it only upto 1 place of decimal. Right now, I get 6 places if I use %f. How do I get only upto 1 place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
printf("%.1f", min);
```

See any reference such as [this](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) for details.